# Search Windows files for a specific number of characters

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I am using Windows 7.  Here is what I could do with the old Windows XP search that I cannot do with Windows 7, Agent Ransack, Everythig or any of the others...
Here is an example of some music files I have stored in various folders on my C Drive.

```
Sting – Fragile [pp] ##### .mp3
Sting – Shape of my heart [pp] #### .mp3
Fleetwood – Never going back [fj] ### .mp3
Elton John – Funeral for a friend [po] ##### .mp3
Supertramp – School [po] #### .mp3
Supertramp – Crime of the Century [po]### .mp3
Supertramp – Cannonball [po] ### .mp3
Acoustic Alchemy – Clean air [fj] #### .mp3
Parov Stelar – Matilda [es] ##### .mp3
Parov Stelar – Hurt [es] ### .mp3
Eberspacher – Sand [ch] #### .mp3
```

What I want to do:

- I want to search my Music Folder for only those file names that contain 5 #####, or
- I only want to search for those file names that contain 2 ##

It does not work. It brings up every single file that contains a #, no matter how many or how few.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The # signs were confusing me a little. So if you are trying to search for something that has 2 '#' signs in the name, you could so something like

`content:~=##`

replacing the two '#' signs with whatever you were searching for.

Comment: OK, the number of #'s in the name determine my degree of "likeness" for a song :o) example: 6 # means I love the songs; 4 # means I like the songs a lot;  1 # means the songs are ok.  Say I want to find only those file names that contain 6 # - I can't seem to get your suggestion to work - it still brings up all 5000 files that contain a # in the name - no matter how many